# Conditional compilation in rollup

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

How can I exclude some part of code in file (not the file itself but only few lines) from compiling into bundle? In C# it looks like

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Is it possible for js files compiling with rollup?

Answer (score 1):

**rollup-plugin-jscc**

Possibly you need [rollup-plugin-jscc](https://github.com/aMarCruz/rollup-plugin-jscc#usage), but I'm not sure about it's state in 2022 :(

In usage section of linked README.md file you can find example:

```
/*#if _DEBUG
import mylib from 'mylib-debug';
//#else */
import mylib from 'mylib'
//#endif

mylib.log('Starting $_APPNAME v$_VERSION...')
```

**@rollup/plugin-alias**

Another solution is a little bit different:

```js
/*START.DEBUG_ONLY*/
import 'robot3/debug';
/*END.DEBUG_ONLY*/
import {...} from 'robot3';
```

Also you can use official [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias) to mock `import 'robot3/debug'`, but this approach needs empty mock-file for replacement, what is not so clean.

rollup.config.js

```js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
module.exports = {
  input: ...,
  output: ...,
  plugins: [
    ...,
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'robot3/debug', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/mocks/empty.js') },
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Please include a demonstration as to [how this tool solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) as part of your answer.